# Rotate 360 panoramic image with the device motion or with the gesture recognition Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, core-motion

I am trying to do use a 360 panoramic image, display it on the iPhone screen and go through it with phone motion.
I was looking on the internet and I just found out that we can use the `UIScrollView` for a 180 panoramic image but I still can't find any solution for the 360 one.
could anyone give me a hint for it, please?

Comment: Have a go. Hit a problem. Ask for help with a specific issue.